# Rename/renumerate files in directory

Tags: linux, bash, rename

In some dir I have many files named

> ...
> DSC_0002
>     DSC_0005
>     DSC_0010
> ...

I want rename/renumerate files

> FILE_0001
>     FILE_0002
> ...

Maby, I will need begin numeration NOT from 0001

Comment: This is **very** similar to, although not necessarily an exact duplicate of, my question [Rename multiple directories decrementing sequence number?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57484/2465) on [unix.se]. [David Dai's answer here](http://superuser.com/a/979094/53590) is also *very* similar to [Gilles' answer over there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57485/2465).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I would like to stress some differences from _Gilles the wise_ answer and _David Dai the good young_  one. :-) Style, solidity and safeness. Working from a different path implies additional precautions... that can be avoided when unneeded as Gilles did and I and David did not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the directory that contains these files is /path/to/dir
the script you need will look like this:

```
start=1
cd "/path/to/dir"
for file in ./*;do
  mv "${file}" "FILE_$(printf "%04d" $start)"
  start=$((start+1))
done
```

Comment: __Warning:__ 1. you will move the files in the _remote path_ to the directory from where you are running the script and not renaming where they are.  2. If in the path there are some spaces an you did not protect that value in the script, it will try to move the split directory name  in `FILE_0001` ... Example `/path/to/dir old/*` it will try to move `mv /path/to/dir FILE_0001` and `mv old FILE_0002`

Comment: An song one time said _ops I did it again_  :)) `cd "/path to my/dir"`. If there is a space in the path it will fail to change and it will split rename all the current directories. 8-O Of course there is no problem if there are no spaces as in `/path/to/dir`.

Comment: You're welcome, it is not so much about script writing, it's more about to __extend their use once that you write__. I mean today you write it for a purpose, and it works fine; tomorrow you will use to another purpose expecting it works fine too. Each time you have to think about all strange problem that can arise, because [if they exist they will come](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law) :-) and of course __even more when you move or erase files__ or you __execute commands with sudo__. :-)

Comment: This is file from camera, names NOT contain spaces (DSC_{number}.jpg)
Some files was be deleted. I do not want to have gaps in the numbering. The above script is enough. Thank you.

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor: I leave the comments and we correct the scripts, because the question you did will be useful for other people too (at least we hope). We have to remember that in many camera types it's possible to decide the prefix for the _filenames_ and to store them in subdirectories: in both cases the spaces are allowed characters.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ls | awk '{printf "mv %s FILE_%04d\n",$0,NR ;} ' | bash
```

- make sure no file have funny names.
- `remove |` bash part to have a preview.
- use `NR+666` to start at 667.
- use `%02d` or `%06d` to genrate 01 or 000001 like figure.

Comment: Warning in general it [is not safe to parse the output of ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/66388)... that means check if there are not _funny names_ as the ones with a space in the middle :-) At least the space problem you can fix with some _gym_ inside the brackets: instead of `printf "mv %s FILE_%04d\n"` you can use `printf "mv \"%s\" \"FILE_%04d\"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
Counter=${1:-1}   # It will take the starting number as 1st parameter
WhichDir=${2:-.}  # It will take the path as 2nd parameter

                  # We try to see if the directory exists and if you can go there
(cd "$WhichDir" 2>/dev/null) || { echo "# $WhichDir NOT FOUND " ; exit 1; }

cd "$WhichDir"                            # it exists and you can go there
shopt -s nullglob                         # see notes
for f in DSC_*                            # for all the files in this dir
do
  New_Name=$(printf "FILE_%04d.jpg" $Counter)
                                          # change .jpg in what you need
  Counter=$(($Counter +1))                # increase the counter
  echo "mv -i \"$f\" \"$New_Name\" "      # the -i will prompt before overwrite
  # mv -i "$f" "$New_Name"                # uncomment this line to make it works
exit 0
```

**Notes**

- When you *play* with `mv` can be dangerous. It can overwrite existing files. It can move/rename directory. So it's better to have a visual check before to execute a script. Then you can pipe its output in a shell:
  e.g.  `./Myscript.sh`, it's all ok? If yes then you can write `./Myscript.sh | /bin/bash` (or you can modify it wiping out the "echo" or the comment in the following line).
- It's better to write `mv -i`: it will prompt before overwrite
- If there are no `DSC_*` files in current directory the `shopt -s nullglob` will avoid expansion errors.
- In general [it is not safe to parse the *output of `ls`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/66388) even if in your case it should be not a real problem, because you should have for the files the standard name from camera `DSC_nnnn.jpg`.
- Usually there is an extension (maybe `.jpg` or `.tif` or `.raw`)... change it or erase it in the script to fit your needs.